# Redirecting JSF errors to log file

Tags: jsf, logging, system.out

How can I redirect all the JSF error log messages to a log file? Currently it is being written to a `SystemOut.log` file.

I tried to change the `System.out` to a custom `PrintStream` which will write to a log file and it is logging the system out statements to the log file. But the JSF error messages are still being written to the `SystemOut.log` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mojarra uses the [`java.util.logging`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) logger. So all you need to do is to supply or change the `logging.properties` file in the runtime classpath. You can if necessary override/specify the properties file location using the VM argument `-Djava.util.logging.config.file`.

Another way is to configure it at the servletcontainer level. It's unclear which one you're using, but the exact filename `SystemOut.log` is typical for among others WebSphere. You can instead also just configure tracing/logging in its admin console.

Comment: @BaluC It worked. Awesome!! We were using SLF4j so used the jul-to-slf4j bridge to redirect the java.util logs to our logs. Thanks alot :)